# Check if user has put " or ' in string input (Discord py Rewrite bot)

Tags: python, string, bots, discord

I have a command in my Discord bot that repeats back whatever the user puts after the command call.

Ex: `.botSay hello` results in the bot replying: `hello`

However, when the user inputs a string that contains " or ', I get the following error:

`Unexpected quote mark, '"', in non-quoted string`

I've tried to check if the input contains either " or ' first and aborting the command if so, but when I try to check by using:

`if("\"" in userInput):`

It does not return True, meaning that it does not "see" the " in the string.

Any idea how to catch a " or ' in user input?

Thanks.

Comment: So essentially you need to look for the same things that are in a sql injection attack. That's essentially the problem you are having.

Comment: Not using an SQL database... does that matter?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. This is not exactly a sql injection because you aren't using sql, but what I meant is that this is the kind of thing that causes sql injection. Sanitizing user input. So the same approach for preventing sql injection will apply.

Unfortunately a lot of the built in methods use database modules, so you need to build your own function to do it. But if you start looking into how sql injection is done it should lead you down the right path. In fact if you google, sql injection "or '", you will get results on exactly that.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: I can't find a good source explaining how to make a function that will check for " or '... any links would be appreciated.